# Python, first time using Decimal and quantize

Tags: python, string, dictionary, decimal

I was just wondering if anybody had any input on how to improve this code.  My goal is for it to be as pythonic as possible since I'm trying to really learn python well.  This program works fine, but if you see anything that you think could be done to improve (not major changes, just basic "Im new to python" stuff) this program please let me know.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from decimal import *


print "Welcome to the checkout counter!  How many items are you purchasing today?"

numOfItems = int(raw_input())

dictionary = {}

for counter in range(numOfItems):

    print "Please enter the name of product", counter + 1
    currentProduct = raw_input()    

    print "And how much does", currentProduct, "cost?"
    currentPrice = float(raw_input())

    dictionary.update({currentProduct:currentPrice})

print "Your order was:"

subtotal = 0
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():

    subtotal = subtotal + value
    stringValue = str(value)
    print key, "$" + stringValue

tax = subtotal * .09
total = subtotal + tax
total = Decimal(str(total)).quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding = ROUND_DOWN)

stringSubtotal = str(subtotal)
stringTotal = str(total)

print "Your subtotal comes to", "$" + stringSubtotal + ".", " With 9% sales tax, your total is $" + stringTotal + "."

print "Please enter cash amount:"
cash = Decimal(raw_input()).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))

change = cash - total
stringChange = str(change)

print "I owe you back", "$" + stringChange

print "Thank you for shopping with us!"
```

Comment: I think your program need some Exception Handling for illegal input

Comment: Better suited for codereview.sx?

Comment: @nneonneo yes, it probably would be better suited for codereview.sx, but i figured since I am new to this that there'd probably be some blazing errors that could bring up more interesting ways to do things.  But you might be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Call the product dictionary "products" or some similarly descriptive name, instead of just "dictionary"
2. Generally, if you are iterating over a range, use `xrange` instead of `range` for better performance (though it's a very minor nitpick in an app like this)
3. You can use `subtotal = sum(dictionary.itervalues())` to quickly add up all the item prices, without having to use the loop.
4. You should definitely use Decimal throughout to avoid inaccuracies due to `float`.
5. You can use a formatting string like `'%.2f' % value` (old-style format) or `'{:.2f}' .format(value)` (new-style format) to print out values with two decimal places.
6. The tax value should be a constant, so it can be changed easily (it's used in two places, once for the calculation and once for the display).

Answer (score 1):

- Updating a dictionary, I would use `dict[key] = value`, rather than `dict.update({key:value})`
- Instead of concatenating strings, try using format specification. This looks cleaner and saves you having to convert values to strings explicitly.

  - C-style: `"Qty: %d, Price: %f" % (qty, price)`
  - string.format: `"Qty: {0}, Price {1}".format(qty, price)`

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I actually used the dict.update because I found somewhere on stack overflow where someone said it was better to use that than dict[key] = value.  Do you have a reason you prefer one over the other?  The other person didn't have a real reason either, they just said that's what they do.

Comment: To be honest, the main reason is simply that I've always done it that way. I also think it reads more clearly, and maps directly to how you retrieve values from a dictionary: `dict[key] = value` -> `value = dict[key]`. `dict.update()` is mostly useful for combining multiple dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

1 to add key-value in a dict, you can use:

```
dictionary[currentProduct] = currentPrice
```

but, you don't need a dict in this case, because dict is orderless. You can use a list of tuple.

2 Why not use `Decimal(raw_input())`, then you can do all the calculation in decimal without using floats.

3 To print the result, you don't need convert values to str first, you can use `str.format()`